# Efficient functional algorithm for computing closure under an operator

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

I'm interested in efficient functional algorithms (preferably in Haskell, and even more preferably already implemented as part of a library!) for computing the closure of a container under a unary operator.

A basic and inefficient example of what I have in mind, for lists, is:

```
closure :: Ord a => (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
closure f xs = first_dup (iterate (\xs -> nub $ sort $ xs ++ map f xs) xs) where
    first_dup (xs:ys:rest) = if xs == ys then xs else first_dup (ys:rest)
```

A more efficient implementation keeps tracks of the new elements generated at each stage (the "fringe") and doesn't apply the function to elements to which it has already been applied:

```
closure' :: Ord a => (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
closure' f xs = stable (iterate close (xs, [])) where
    -- return list when it stabilizes, i.e., when fringe is empty
    stable ((fringe,xs):iterates) = if null fringe then xs else stable iterates

    -- one iteration of closure on (fringe, rest);  key invariants:
    -- (1) fringe and rest are disjoint; (2) (map f rest) subset (fringe ++ rest)
    close (fringe, xs) = (fringe', xs') where
        xs' = sort (fringe ++ xs)
        fringe' = filter (`notElem` xs') (map f fringe)
```

As an example, if `xs` is a nonempty sublist of `[0..19]`, then `` closure' (\x->(x+3)`mod`20) xs `` is [0..19], and the iteration stabilizes in 20 steps for `[0]`, 13 steps for `[0,1]`, and 4 steps for `[0,4,8,12,16]`.

Even more efficiency could be gotten using a tree-based ordered-set implementation.
Has this been done already?  What about the related but harder question of closure under binary (or higher-arity) operators?

Comment: Does laziness matter?

Comment: Not in the applications I have in mind, where I have finite set that is already closed and I want to compute the closure of a subset.

Answer (score 7):

How about something like this which uses the Hash Array Mapped Trie data structures in [`unordered-containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-HashSet.html). For unordered-containers `member` and `insert` are *O(min(n,W))* where *W* is the length of the hash.

```
module Closed where

import Data.HashSet (HashSet)
import Data.Hashable
import qualified Data.HashSet as Set

data Closed a = Closed { seen :: HashSet a, iter :: a -> a } 

insert :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => a -> Closed a -> Closed a
insert a c@(Closed set iter)
  | Set.member a set = c
  | otherwise        = insert (iter a) $ Closed (Set.insert a set) iter

empty :: (a -> a) -> Closed a
empty = Closed Set.empty

close :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => (a -> a) -> [a] -> Closed a
close iter = foldr insert (empty iter)
```

Here's a variation on the above that generates the solution set more lazily, in a breadth-first manner.

```
data Closed' a = Unchanging | Closed' (a -> a) (HashSet a) (Closed' a)

close' :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => (a -> a) -> [a] -> Closed' a
close' iter = build Set.empty where
  inserter :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => a -> (HashSet a, [a]) -> (HashSet a, [a])
  inserter a (set, fresh) | Set.member a set = (set, fresh)
                          | otherwise        = (Set.insert a set, a:fresh)
  build curr [] = Unchanging
  build curr as =
    Closed' iter curr $ step (foldr inserter (curr, []) as)
  step (set, added) = build set (map iter added)

-- Only computes enough iterations of the closure to 
-- determine whether a particular element has been generated yet
-- 
-- Returns both a boolean and a new 'Closed'' value which will 
-- will be more precisely defined and thus be faster to query
member :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => a -> Closed' a -> (Bool, Closed' a)
member _ Unchanging = False
member a c@(Closed' _ set next) | Set.member a set = (True, c)
                                | otherwise        = member a next

improve :: Closed' a -> Maybe ([a], Closed' a)
improve Unchanging = Nothing
improve (Closed' _ set next) = Just (Set.toList set, next)

seen' :: Closed' a -> HashSet a
seen' Unchanging = Set.empty
seen' (Closed' _ set Unchanging) = set
seen' (Closed' _ set next)       = seen' next
```

And to check

```
>>> member 6 $ close (+1) [0]
...

>>> fst . member 6 $ close' (+1) [0]
True
```

Comment: This is a nice "depth-first" solution to my main question, but I'm left wondering how it would scale to situations with multiple unary operators or with binary (and higher-arity) operators.  Scheduling the inserts seems tricky.

Comment: I added a breadth-first method, but I'm not sure how to do higher-arity operators in a nice way.

Comment: @lambdacalculator Could you provide a source for higher-arity closures? I only know of closures on binary relations and I'd like to learn more.

Comment: I released this code on Hackage at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/closure and I'd love to continue the discussion on Github https://github.com/tel/closure